# TeamCity build number override from script

Tags: shell, teamcity

I have a problem with setting up the build number for the build from the script. I use the shell command in TeamCity build step:

```
   echo "##teamcity[buildNumber '%build.counter%.%tp.environment%.%tp.environment.contentSpreadsheetSelectOverride%']"
```

And it results in build number:

```
\''868.car_hdev.Dev'\'
```

When I perform the test:

```
echo '%build.counter%.%tp.environment%.%tp.environment.contentSpreadsheetSelectOverride%'
```

It gives me the right output:

```
868.car_hdev.Dev
```

I believe I do everything as instructed here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Reporting+Build+Number

Do you have any idea why there are additional characters in the resulting build number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to change:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
```

To:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

In the build step script.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder what is the reason...